# Why is my Eclipse IDE showing a launch error?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, webdriver, launch

I had to recently change my laptop and now it is showing launch error whwn I try to execute something.

[image]

Comment: When using Java 15 you need to install [_Java 15 Support for Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17)_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417). If this does not help, is there something in the error log?

Comment: @VishnuVichus JDK version? Eclipse version? Selenium version?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: @DebanjanB According to the screenshot: JDK 15.0.1, Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16) or Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) and the Selenium version should not be relevant here.

Comment: @VishnuVichus can you run eclipse through command prompt <path of eclipse.exe>  
 -clean and check if it is working fine?